# Multiple comparisons with genetic * environment interactions

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, genetics

I am analysing the next models with logistic or linear regression: Y = G*E + confounders, where G is a genetic variable (SNP) and E is an environment variable. 
The problem is the next: I have 13 SNPs (not correlated, not LD), 20 environment variables and 15 response variables to analyse. 
What is the number of tests in this context for apply the Bonferroni correction?
I thing 13*20 (number of SNPs * environment variables )

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late, but just in case it isn't.

Assuming you are doing one model to test interaction for each combination of $G_i$ and $E_i$ for 15 phenotypes, it would not be $13 \cdot 20$, rather the number of tests would be $15 \cdot 13 \cdot 20$ assuming that your phenotypes are uncorrelated.

If you think about the inflation of type-1 error, you are testing against $H_0$ $13 \cdot 20$ times, then subsequently doing *that* 15 times.

You can also look into alternate approaches like [MultiPhen](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3342314/) and other such algorithms.